# How to embed vrml animation on android html application

Tags: android, html, embed, vrml, wrl

I want to embed a vrml animation (file type = .wrl) in my android html application, build with CLI phonegap.

It is working correctly with a JPG image, but I can not make it run with my vrml file.

Here is a simple example that what I want to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<embed src="/sdcard/Documents/DataBase/vrml2.wrl" type="model/vrml" width=600 height=750>
</body>
</html>
```

On my Android Samsung Tablet, nothing is displayed here.

But if I change the embed line with this one:

```
<embed src="/sdcard/Documents/DataBase/DemoFile.jpg" width=600 height=750>
```

My JPG image is displayed on my tablet.

I try also this:

```
<embed src="/sdcard/Documents/DataBase/vrml2.wrl" width=600 height=750>
```

In this case, the first line of the wrl file is displayed on the tablet screen, in plain text.

I have installed the FreeX3D android application. No problem to load the vrml file via the FreeX3D application itself. It is working OK.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Marcel

PS: This is working OK in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7, with Cortona VRML software install.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that android's WebView doesn' support it ...

Comment: I have check WebView sites and see no example of it, but I have never used WebView, so maybe I missing something.